# Submit multiple checkboxes to multiple tables of single database

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I have 4 checkboxes, so when i click on submit i want each of the checkbox to get updated in different tables in single database through php.
i.e

Ex: 
    1. first_eventcheckbox  --> firstevent table (database)

```
2. sec_eventcheckbox    --> secondevent table (database)

3. third_eventcheckbox  --> thirdevent table (database)

4. fourth_eventcheckbox --> fourthevent table (database)
```

All the tables are in same database.

So, when i click submit i need selected checkbox to send to selected table

I need php code for this, i.e php code for sending these values to different tables.
Any help is appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add your php code here...

Comment: I din't code it. I have a html page and i am searching for code to enter these values using post method. www.tynate.in please check this website what i have developed. I need those checkboxes to different tables.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. It sounds like it is time to hire someone.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this,

```
if($_POST['first_checkbox']) {
    // insert to first table
}


if($_POST['second_checkbox']) {
    // insert to second table
}

... so on.
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try using this method

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_POST['event_name']) && !empty($_POST['event_name'])) {
    if($_POST['event_name']=='faceart') {
        //insert into first table
    } elseif ($_POST['event_name']=='dance') {
        //insert into second table
    } elseif ($_POST['event_name']=='nailart') {
        //insert into third table
    } elseif ($_POST['event_name']=='treasurehunt') {
        //insert into fourth table
    }
}
```

This answer is provided according to your link : http://www.tynate.in/

Comment: Thanks for your effort "Krishna Gupta"